# Bash / Regular Expression Conversion

Tags: regex, bash

I'm new to RegEx and have a working RegEx pattern that doesn't seem to be Bash / Shell compatible. I've been reading around that \d isn't supportable in Bash. Can anyone help me try to understand the incompatibilities and make this expression work?

```
#!/bin/bash
passwordToTest="test@"

regExPattern="(?=^.{8,255}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*"

if [[ $passwordToTest =~ $regExPattern ]]; then
echo "$passwordToTest is valid"
exit 0
else
echo "$passwordToTest is invalid"
exit 1
fi
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are a dozen separate checks. Why are they all crammed into a single regex?

Comment: If you read that `\d` isn't supported in Bash, why do you persist in using it?  In an argument with Bash about what it implements, you're very unlikely to win!

Comment: Hi Toby, I think you've misunderstood me. I wanted to see how you'd replace the \d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another construct that bash regex doesn't handle which is lookahead.

Decoding what regex is doing

```
(?=^.{8,255}$)      at least 8 and no more than 255 characters
( either
  (?=.*\d)      a digit  
  (?=.*[A-Z])       and an uppercase
  (?=.*[a-z])       and a lowercase
| or
  (?=.*\d)      and a digit
  (?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])    and a special char
  (?=.*[a-z])       and a lowercase
| or
  (?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])    a special char
  (?=.*[A-Z])       and an uppercase
  (?=.*[a-z])       and a lowercase
| or
  (?=.*\d)      a digit
  (?=.*[A-Z])       and an uppercase
  (?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])    and a special char
)^.*
```

This can be done either using grep if it supports PCRE

```
if grep -Pq "$regExPattern" <<<$passwordToTest >/dev/null; then
```

or writing logic with bash language

```
if
    containsDigit=0
    containsUpper=0
    containsLower=0
    containsSpecial=0
    lang=$LANG LANG=C
    [[ $passwordToTest = *[0-9]* ]] && containsDigit=1
    [[ $passwordToTest = *[A-Z]* ]] && containsUpper=1
    [[ $passwordToTest = *[a-z]* ]] && containsLower=1
    [[ $passwordToTest = *[^0-9A-Za-z]* ]] && containsSpecial=1
    LANG=$lang

    (( ${#passwordToTest} >=8 )) &&
    (( ${#passwordToTest} <=255 )) &&
    (( containsDigit + containsUpper + containsLower + containsSpecial >= 3 ))
then
```

Comment: Hi Nahuel. Thanks a lot for this. It makes a lot more sense here. I quite like your if statement logic that's more my level.